# Why am i not allowed to create an access object. Is there a special reference that should be referenced? Run-time err: -2146959355 (80080005)

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection

The error comes in this line: Set App...Running Access 2003 and trying to open a form in another database. I've done it before but now it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance...

```
Function OpenDB(DatabasePath As String) As Access.Application
    Dim app As Access.Application
    Set app = New Access.Application
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase DatabasePath
    Set OpenDB = app
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling Access 2007 Runtime module it seems to work OK. But it opens the whole application and then the form. What I need is open the form in the calling application, and with the tables in the current application ie. reusing the form in another app. Is that possible?